# Extracting Icon/Thumbnail for a file

Tags: windows, thumbnails, windows-shell

I want to extract the Icon/Thumbnail (different size) of a file from
windows shell on my project. I am able to extract the thumbnail with
out any issue, but the problem came when working with files that don't
have thumbnail view. The issue is I am not able to get the bitmap as
the windows explorer shows. I am getting a black color where explorer
is showing a nice gray shadow.

I have uploaded
1. The image I got for an html file,
2. The image as shown by windows explorer,
3. The sample source code
at
http://www.fileflyer.com/view/seAOcBP

Any help here is appreciated.

Regards,

Manoj

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you save it. To have gradient alpha channel you need to save it as a PNG.

Comment: BMP files with 32bpp support, and can be saved with - usually premultiplied (but theres no real standard one way or the other) - alpha information. Windows XP explorer can and will automatically create alpha thumbnails from such bmp files.